# Xamarin mac crash reporting system

Tags: cocoa, crash-reports, xamarin.mac, raygun

Is there any free tool to get crash reports from my xamarin. mac application?

For now the only tool I found, which has xamarin support is

> Raygan crash reporting system 
>   here is [link](https://raygun.com/products/crash-reporting)

Comment: HockeyApp, the company that Microsoft bought and replaced Insights with and is rebranding to 'Visual Studio Mobile Center' has an `macOS`sdk  (ObjC framework) that I use via a `Xamarin.Mac` Binding project :    https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-ios-mac-os-x-tvos/hockeyapp-for-mac-os-x (FYI: This is the same SDK that Microsoft uses for products such as `OneDrive for Mac`)

Comment: hm, not good news :( not sure if binding library will work ok

Comment: Do you use hockeyapp in your xamarin.mac application?

Comment: Ah, Nice , very good news. I downloaded HockeySDK-Mac from git , here is 'libCrashReporter-MacOSX-Static.a' file inside vendor directory. Is this what I need?

Comment: I'm using the `HockeySDK.framework` from the `Download the SDK` link in the HockeyApp link in my original comment but you could bind to the static library....

Comment: I created binding library from HockeySDK.framework , got no errors . Trying  to include HockeySDK ,but it isn't visible :  
using HockeySDK;

Comment: Did you create the `ApiDefinitions.cs` and `StructsAndEnums.cs` and add them to the binding project? If not, you might want to review https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/binding/objective-c-libraries/ https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/binding/objective-sharpie/

Comment: @SushiHangover Can you share binging library?

Comment: I have started implementing binding library, it seems everything is fine. but can't get crash report in website:

public override void DidFinishLaunching (NSNotification notification)
  {
   HockeyAppLib.BITHockeyManager manager = HockeyAppLib.BITHockeyManager.SharedHockeyManager;
   manager.ConfigureWithIdentifier (new NSString (AppIdentifier));
   manager.StartManager ();
  }